# Check For Constraints Before Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Question: let's say I have 2 tables

```
EnStudents
PnStudents
```

with the same columns

```
ID, Name
```

`EnStudents` has 5 rows

```
1   Jeni
2   Maria
3   John
4   Maria
5   Philip
```

and PNStudents Have 2 Rows 
10   Jeni
13   John

While `PNStudents` Had 2 Rows but has a unique key on `name` column.

Now when I try to insert the rows from `ENStudents` into `PNStudents`, it will obviously raise an error saying that there is a violation of unique key

I need to check which records will cause errors when inserted before I send an insert, so that I can change the conflicting records using TSQL And Adding Some number In Front Of Conflicting Rows

Thanks

Comment: What's your problem? What error are you getting? What have you tried? Please read the following document on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> Now When I Insert The Records From ENStudents To PNStudents It Will Obviously Raise An Error saying that there is violation of unique key..
>
> I need to check which records will cause errors when inserted before I send an insert

Do a group by on name column which will give you dupes..

```
Select name,count(*) as cnt
From 
ENStudents 
group by name
having count(*)>1
```

You also can insert rows like below,so that it wont case constraint violation..This uses "With Ties Option" available from SQL Server 2008

```
Insert Into pnstudents
select top 1 with ties id,name
from 
enstudents
order by
row_number() over (partition by name order by name)
```

Comment: well my mistake i was not that elaborate in question i have updated my question again thanks

Comment: @KhurramSultan:  no issues ,check here and read this link ,you will get amazingly fast answers  ,https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/